# Finding the joint density of two independent exponential distributions

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution, marginal-distribution

16. Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables each having a exponential distribution with mean $λ = 1$.

(a) Find the joint density of $Y_1 = X_1$ and $Y_2 = X_1 + X_2$.

(b) Get the marginal density of $f_{Y_1}(y_1)$ and $f_{Y_2}(y_2)$.

These are what I've found so far.

$$f_{X_1}(x_1)=e^{-x_1}, f_{X_2}(x_2)=e^{-x_2}$$
$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1, x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)=e^{-x_1-x_2}$$

Also, since $Y_1=X1$, $f_{Y_1}(y_1)=e^{-y_1}$ right?
Similarly, since $Y_2=X_1+X_2$, $f_{Y_2}(y_2)=e^{-y_2}$

However, is it guaranteed that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent? or else how can I solve these problems??

Oh, and I haven't learned the Jacobian so it would be grateful if you avoid using it.

Comment: Are you familiar with change of variables method involving Jacobians? Or can you find the joint distribution function of $(Y_1,Y_2)$, and hence find the marginal distributions?

Comment: Sounds like you are asked to find the marginals from the joint density. While it is true that $Y_1$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, you need to derive the density of $Y_1$ from the joint density of $(Y_1,Y_2)$. And no, marginal of $Y_2$ does not make sense.

Comment: Then I wonder if the f(y2)=(y2)e^(-y2)

Comment: For the joint density, try finding the joint cdf $F_{Y_1,Y_2}(y,z)=P(Y_1\le y, Y_2\le z)$ first. Then the joint density is just $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y,z)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial z}F_{Y_1,Y_2}(y,z)$.